# Can't import .obj files into my Nuxt components

Tags: vue.js, three.js, nuxt.js

in my Nuxt project I have a background scene made with Three.js.
Now I want to load an .obj into this scene. So the model has to loaded via the component.

my index.vue component:

```
export default {
  name: 'scene',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if(!this.scene) this.scene = new Scene({
      $canvas: this.$refs.canvas,
    });
  }
}
```

In my .js file(Inside the components, where the .vue is as well):

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import Common from "../Common";
import { OBJLoader2 } from '~/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader2.js';
const Model = require('@/assets/models/background_1.obj')

export default class Model_1{
    constructor(){
        this.init();
    }

    init(){
        var loader = new OBJLoader2();
        console.log(Model)
        loader.load(Model, (root) => {
          Common.scene.add(root);
        });
    }    
}
```

The Nuxt config:

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  build: {
    vendor: ['hammerjs'],
    extend (config, ctx) {
      config.module.rules.push(
      { 
        test: /\.(obj|gltf)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Following error appears: 
`Cannot find module '@/assets/models/background_1.obj'`

I though that the .vue component will look into the assets folder, gets the obj and just reflects the url. But it's looking for a module, which I don't really understand ‍♂️ 
The .obj file is located in the assets/models folder.

Comment: Are you sure `@/` redirects to your desired working directory? Cause in our other imports you use a relative path.

Comment: Well, yes. I tried to load a .json via this way and could get the desired data. It might be the .obj file.

Comment: Ahh so the problem is that my ObjLoader wants a URL. If I import a file via require, it's getting me the content of the file, not the url. Bur how do I get the URL?

Comment: If so can put your file on the `static` folder instead of `assets` which gets mapped to `/` and either use `\`${window.location.href}/models/background_1.obj\`` or just `/models/background_1.obj` might work as well. If you use the window method and you have SSR enabled you will have to make sure it does not execute on the server side since window is not defined which will cause an error

Answer (score 0):

Ok, although every doc said that if the file is in `static/file` you'll have to use the src `static/file`. Now that did not work for me, but just using `file` as source worked. It's working, but can someone please clarify this since I've been on this problem since 2 days and many migraines

Comment: Hello, could you please post the complete solution? What kind of loaders do we need, and what would be the correct way to import the url? It would help me so much! thnx

Answer (score 0):

Transfer the file to static folder example static/images/background.png
Then omit the `@/assets/`

```
var textureURL = "images/background.png";
var texture = textureLoader.load(textureURL);
```